# "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'" when trying to deploy Django server on Azure

Tags: python, django, azure, azure-web-app-service

After I tried to deploy my Django website on Azure, I got an error saying:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'
```

I added a requirements.txt in the root directory of my Django project, am I missing anything else? I've tried to install Django from Kudu BASH but it gets stuck on "Cleaning Up".

Here is the full error: https://pastebin.com/z5xxqM08

I built the site using Django-2.2 and Python 3.6.8.

Comment: Once I mispelled `requirements.txt` :-) are you sure in the root with right name

Comment: @YugandharChaudhari Its spelled correctly

Comment: Did you install what was in requirements.txt?

Comment: @MatthewGaiser I got it to work

Comment: @explodingfilms101, how did you resolve?

Comment: @Don I believe it was an issue with my requirements.txt not registering with Azure. That or the incorrect Django version was indicated in the requirements.txt file.

Answer (score 2):

Just summarized as an answer for other people. According to your error information, I can see that you tried to deploy your Django app to Azure WebApp on Linux based on Docker. So there are two offical documents will help as below.

1. [Quickstart: Create a Python app in Azure App Service on Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/quickstart-python)
2. [Configure a Linux Python app for Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/how-to-configure-python)

The error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'` indicated that there is not `django` package installed on the container of Azure Linux WebApp.

Due to the content of `Container characteristics` of #2 document above as below,

[image]

> To install additional packages, such as Django, create a requirements.txt file in the root of your project using `pip freeze > requirements.txt`. Then, publish your project to App Service using Git deployment, which automatically runs `pip install -r requirements.txt` in the container to install your app's dependencies.

So the possible reason is the `requirements.txt` file not in the corrent path of your project or container after deployed, which path should be `/home/site/wwwroot/requirements.txt` on the container or the root of your project like the offical sample [`Azure-Samples/djangoapp`](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/djangoapp) on GitHub.

Comment: I do have the exact same problem as OP and I do for sure have a "requirements.txt" at the root of my project.
The only difference from the document is that I am not using Git Deployment, I am instead uploading a zip file with the code, but the container initialization process is still there... I don't get what is happening

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. `requirements.txt` was in my repository, but randomly I started getting the same error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'` after changing a setting or restarting the service or something. Nothing I could do, change the setting, or reboot repeatedly fixed it. Finally what worked for me was this:

Make a small change to the code and commit it, and push it up to the app service.

This fixed it for me. It has happened a couple times now and every time this solution has worked for me. It seems like the App Service sometimes gets in this state and needs to be jostled with this trick?

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same issue though Django was there in requirements, I added setting in configuration section from referring following link and redeployed and it worked. I hope it work for you.

**SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT=true**

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-deployment-technologies

Refer : Remote build on Linux Section