# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django', with virtual environment Python3.8

Tags: python, django, apache

Trying to run Django App along with Apache2 in Python3.8 Virtual environment. When I enter in to the python shell, I could import django. But when accessing webpage, it says "django not found"

As per the /var/log/apache2/error.log, following is the error

[Sun May 03 02:56:14.209910 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 21516] [remote 192.168.1.5:58968]     from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
[Sun May 03 02:56:14.209966 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 21516] [remote 192.168.1.5:58968] ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'

**wsgi.py:**

import os,sys

sys.path.append('/var/www/html/django-venv-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages')

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'filebucket.settings')

application = get_wsgi_application()

**default.conf**

(django-venv-py3.8) ramesh@Orktion:.../filebucket$ cat /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

```
<Directory /var/www/html/django-venv-py3.8/filebucket/filebucket>
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>

WSGIDaemonProcess filebucket python-path=/var/www/html/django-venv-py3.8/filebucket python-home=/var/www/html/django-venv-py3.8
WSGIProcessGroup filebucket
WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/django-venv-py3.8/filebucket/filebucket/wsgi.py

Alias /static /var/www/html/django-venv-py3.8/filebucket/static
<Directory /var/www/html/django-venv-py3.8/filebucket/static>
    Require all granted
</Directory>

Alias /media /var/www/html/django-venv-py3.8/filebucket/media
<Directory /var/www/html/django-venv-py3.8/filebucket/media>
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

[image]

I have followed some troubleshooting articles, but no luck

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/58449933/7049436 check this link out

Comment: and this too https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-run-django-with-mod_wsgi-and-apache-with-a-virtualenv-python-environment-on-a-debian-vps

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try to install `Django` using the following command in windows CMD, and then try to execute it again:
`python -m django`

I hope this works :)

Comment: That command tells Python [to run the `django` module as a script](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-m), and would only work if Django is already installed.